# How do I convert a map object to list and also assign to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Although documentation tells me that I should be able to convert a map object to list using `list(map_object)` this is not working the way I want it to.

I have a simple program:

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
print(list(arr)) #this works
list_arr = list(arr)
print(list_arr) #doesn't work
```

I expect:

```
3
14 23 1
[14, 23, 1]
[14, 23, 1]
>>>
```

But I get:

```
3
14 23 1
[14, 23, 1]
[]
```

Any thoughts why?

Comment: `map` is one time consumable. It is already used in the first print, hence it's value is exhausted. You have to assign to some variable prior to printing.

Comment: Thanks Austin & DYZ! Yes that worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi @arpi I have tried to summarize whatever is present on the comments in my answer below please take a look :)

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) gives you an iterator, which you can only `consume`, or iterate through once, after which the iterator is empty, which is what happens when you did `print(list(arr))`

Instead assign your `list(arr)` to a variable, like `list_arr = list(arr)` and then you can use that in the subsequent code

```
In [144]: n = int(input())                                                                                                                                                        
3

In [145]: arr = map(int, input().split())                                                                                                                                         
14 23 1
#list_arr can be used for subsequent code, you have consumed arr completely
In [146]: list_arr = list(arr)                                                                                                                                                    

In [147]: print(list_arr)                                                                                                                                                         
[14, 23, 1]
#Iterator is empty after using it once
In [148]: print(list(arr))                                                                                                                                                        
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented `map` is one time consumable, so you can do something like so:

```py
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
list_arr = list(arr)
print(list_arr) #this works
```

And you can use the `list_arr` value many times.

Answer (score -1):

Once you will:

- Learn/know about how Python generator works;
- Write/create your own generators.

You will easily figure out this problem (looks strange but very useful and simple).

> Thanks to **yield** keyword & **StopIteration** exception & some magic methods as these play great roles in writing our own generator.

```
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> arr = [1729, 67, 92]
>>> gen = map(str, arr)
>>> 
>>> # 1st item
... 
>>> gen.__next__()
'1729'
>>> 
>>> # 2nd item
... 
>>> gen.__next__()
'67'
>>> 
>>> # 3rd item
... 
>>> gen.__next__()
'92'
>>> 
>>> # This will not work (Exception beacause no more items are in generator, over)
... 
>>> gen.__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

So if you will focus on below kind of examples, you will be confused (1st time).

```
>>> arr2 = list(gen)
>>> arr2
['1729', '67', '92']
>>>
>>> # Generator has already been iterated, so no more items
...
>>> gen.__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
>>> arr2 = list(gen)
>>> arr2
[]
>>>
```

Just for references, have a look at below links:

- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator
- https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions

Answer (score -2):

Simply, you can not do like: `list_arr = list(arr)`. Because as mentioned by the above answers, it already consumes.

One way to workaround this, then you have to get each member and create a new object.

Comment: On the contrary, that's exactly how one _should_ do: convert the iterator into a list.